# Does vinegar increase the iron we can digest from Spinach?

Tags: vinegar, nutrient-composition, spinach

I heard tale of people using vinegar to break down or concentrate the digestible iron in spinach. Is this true?

If it's true, the key things to know would be:

- What vinegar do you use?
- How do you prepare it?
- Does it impair the flavour?
- Is the benefit measurable and significant?

My thoughts are there is something in it in a similar manner to [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7397/why-would-cooked-spinach-contain-more-iron-than-raw).

Answer (score 1):

You know, I have always liked to eat spinach with vinegar.  Just steamed and with a splash of plain white vinegar.  It is a very common way to eat spinach around here.

Anyway, I suppose it could have some affect on iron absorption.  Large amounts of vitamin C can increase non-heme iron absorption by as much as 200%.  This article, http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jf0203040, seems to indicate that acetic acid, the main component in vinegar, may also increase iron absorption.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the vitamin C content in the vinegar is making the iron in cooked spinach more digestible?

There are quite a few recipes online that simply combine sauteed spinach and balsamic vinegar- evidently it's a popular side dish.  I see some people use other types of vinegar as well.  You can also make a wilted spinach salad with a bacon dripping-and-vinegar dressing.  That makes a delicious lunch if you add grilled chicken, red onions, and some bits of bacon.