# Volumetric conversion between frozen and fresh spinach

Tags: substitutions, frozen, fresh

I like to freeze my spinach and use it in smoothies.  When I bring it out of the freezer, I crush it as much as I can.  I then measure it out in 2 cup quantities.  How much would this equal in fresh spinach.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My frozen spinach doesn't change in volume enough to notice. I think it would be the same- at least unless it has freezer burn and dried out.

Comment: There was a question on here somewhere about comparing iron content in fresh vs. cooked spinich ... I would assume a similar density change in fresh vs. frozen.

Comment: found it -- https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7397/67 ... so 3.57 mg vs 2.71 mg / 100g would suggest that you'd need 30% more by weight ... and if you compare the volume of 1lb of cooked spinach volume vs. 1.3lbs of fresh, you could figure out the difference by volume.

Comment: Surely if you have frozen it yourself, then you should know what the quantities are.  When initially freezing it, write on the bag/container what the quantity is - problem solved?

Comment: Freeze the spinach in 2-cup portions. ;) I always wonder why the use volume instead of weight for measuring solids... use weight instead.

Answer (score 2):

Best to use a scale. Measure how much fresh spinach you normally use and use the same weight for frozen. Moisture content for frozen spinach may be slightly less than fresh but it should not matter that much. There are very few occasions when volume measurements are actually necessary and a weight measurement is not appropriate.